# Self-study curriculum

Tags: linear-algebra, education

May I ask some suggestions on a self-study or self-paced curriculum if I want to study matrices and their eigenvalues. I really do not have a good Mathematics background but I really think that I would need a good grip on eigenvalues and the processes to determine them (for a future work). Should I start with Gilbert Strang's linear algebra? Your suggestions would be of great help to me. Thank you.

Comment: search for "introductory linear algebra" or "matrix analysis" in this site to see some reccomendations. Also take a look to [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-70873-7_7), for example. However it seems not so elementary.

Comment: For the records: the book in the above comment can be downloaded by here: https://sci-hub.hk/https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-70873-7_7# but it's far from being very elementary.

Try with Sheldon Axler - Linear Algebra done right-

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions